# findViewById(int) returns null for custom views, but not Android built-ins

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

**The Situation:** I have some custom components in my layout. I have a common layout frame that I load in my Activity base class's `onCreate()`, and then load my content layouts in my implementations using an inflater, setting the root to the content column of the main layout.

**The Problem:** When I grab a reference to the Views, to actually extract the user's input, `Activity.findViewById()` returns `null`. It is perhaps a clue that the CheckBox and Button I have in the layout do NOT return `null`; I get a valid reference to the widget.

**Things I've Tried:** I know I am properly loading and inflating the layout xml, because everything shows up, and the standard Views in the same layout can be found by ID. I can interact with my Views and put content into them and everything, but I can't get a reference to them in my code.

I have tried cleaning the project, multiple times. `R.id` is fresh and up-to-date.

I have checked the Console and Error Log, and there's no UI/XML errors reported.

I tried getting a handle to the root layout of the content I loaded for this activity, and calling `View.findViewById()` to get my references, and that returns `null`, too. If I examine the layout in the debugger, I can drill down and find my Views in `mChildren`.

**Perhaps another clue:**

```
public VideoChooser(Context pCtxt, AttributeSet pAttrs)
{
    super(pCtxt, pAttrs);
    Log.d("VideoChooser", "Expected ID: " + R.id.vchShareVids + " | actual: " + getId());
}
```

will result in the following output:

`DEBUG/VideoChooser(10372): Expected ID: 2131296271 | actual: 268435456`

The ID assigned to the View doesn't match the ID in `R.id`! Why would that be? I know it's loading the `android:id` attribute, or else it would be -1 (`View.NO_ID`).

**The Common Layout Frame:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:foo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.foo"
    android:id="@+id/common_frame" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- top banner -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/frame_header" android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">

        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/banner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- content column -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/frame_content" android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp" android:layout_marginRight="32dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**The Content Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:foo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.foo"
    android:id="@+id/content_panel" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.foo.view.VideoChooser android:id="@+id/vchShareVids"
        foo:prompt_text="@string/prompt_share_vid" foo:prompt_size="16dp"
        foo:preview_height="80dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp" android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true" />
    <com.foo.view.ContactChooser android:id="@+id/cchRecipients"
        foo:prompt_text="@string/prompt_share_email" foo:prompt_size="16dp"
        foo:preview_lines="3" foo:dialog_title="Pretend you are picking contacts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp" android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true" />
    <com.foo.view.TextChooser android:id="@+id/tchDescription"
        foo:prompt_text="@string/prompt_share_description" foo:prompt_size="16dp"
        foo:preview_lines="1" foo:dialog_title="@string/title_msg_chooser_dlg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp" android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true" />

    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/chkReshare" android:text="@string/prompt_reshare"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true" android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/btnSend" android:text="@string/btn_send"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/btn_width" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Activity Base Class onCreate():**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.common_frame);
}
```

**Activity Implementation onCreate():**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle pState)
{
    super.onCreate(pState);
    load_content_view(R.layout.content_layout);

    ViewGroup tLayout = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.content_panel);

    // These all return null
    mCchVideo = (ContentChooser)tLayout.findViewById(R.id.vchShareVids);
    mCchContact = (ContentChooser)tLayout.findViewById(R.id.cchRecipients);
    mCchDescription = (ContentChooser)tLayout.findViewById(R.id.tchDescription);

    // These return valid references
    mChkReshare = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chkReshare);
    mBtnSend = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSend);

    // ...
}

protected void load_content_view(int pResId)
{
    LinearLayout tColumn = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.frame_content);
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(pResId, tColumn);
}
```

Comment: Provide necessary layouts xml files and onCreate method code

Comment: Problem would be not using setContentView() or If you created View it self was not assigned... For more detail show some code

Comment: Done. Let me know if there's any other code you feel is germain.

Comment: Cant find R.id.givit_content in layout files

Comment: One more question: via setContentView you inflate Common Layout Frame. In load_content_view you trying to find content_panel which presents in Content Layout, but not in Layout Frame. Is here some inaccuracy?

Comment: Correct. Some of this code is not authorized to release to the public yet, so I had to modify some things by hand to maintain the company's privacy. `load_content_view()` should be getting a reference to `frame_content` as the layout root, which is reflected in my latest edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah... I'm an idiot. View was of course setting the correct ID, and then one of my init methods went back and clobbered it.

*facepalm*

Comment: This seems more like a question comment. Its your call whether or not to acknowledge @HighFlyer and yes, it is much appreciated that you closed the question. But you are NOT an idiot! It would be better to write out a clearer explanation here (you overwrote the correct ID set by view?) and leave out the self-deprecation and words like clobbered. No harm done, but don't put yourself down like that!

Answer (score 14):

I had a similar problem and the solution for mine was to make sure the constructor of the custom widget calls

```
super(context, attrs);
```

My constructor didn't pass attrs to super and thus the view id was messed up and the findviewbyId returned null.

Answer (score 1):

It's very difficult to find problem without actual sources. I've created sample project based on your posts and its fully works.
I believe that there is very simple mistake and you'll find it.
If you want, you may [try it](http://www.box.net/shared/ejjbhc1xnm8d97vzao3d)

Comment: the problem is that, yes, it works, and I can get references to UI elements such as Button and CheckBox. But my custom widgets get returned to me as `null` despite showing up in the layout and being fully interactive. This seems to be because their IDs are being set incorrectly in View's constructor, but I have no idea how that could possibly happen.